# Error javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException in JBoss7.3

Tags: jboss, ldap

I'm facing the below error in connecting the LDAP in JBoss 7.3 while deploying the SSL.

> javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException

LDAP is working fine, once we rollback the SSL over the JBoss7.3.

We've tried

1. Reinstall the SSL over the JBoss7.3
2. Check the Certificate

Expecting:
LDAP should be working fine after deploying the SSL over JBossEAP7.3